# In a many-to-many join table, how can I count the number of entries shared by two "owners"?

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, aggregate-functions, distinct

I have a list of movies and a list of tropes. To calculate the similarity between two movies, I am using [cosine differences](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/nlp/cosine-similarity/). If all the weights are even, then it simplifies pretty well:

```
similarity =

(number of shared tropes between both movies)
/
(SQRT(number of tropes from movie 1) + SQRT(number of tropes from movie 2))
```

For example, if movie 1 has tropes 1, 3, and 4, and movie 2 has tropes 1, 4, 6, and 7, then there would be two tropes shared between them and the similarity would be

```
2 / (SQRT(3) + SQRT(4)) = 2 / 3.73... = 0.54
```

My MySQL tables are pretty standard:

```
movies:
- id
- ...

tropes:
- id
- ...

movie_tropes:
- movie_id
- trope_id
```

I can easily count the number of tropes for a movie:

```
SELECT count(distinct trope_id) from movie_tropes where movie_id = 1;
SELECT count(distinct trope_id) from movie_tropes where movie_id = 2;
```

I am a little out of practice with SQL. Is there a simple join-y way to count the number of trope_ids that occur for both movie 1 and movie 2 in this join table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a simple way to count the number of trope_ids that occur for both movie 1 and movie 2?

You can self-join:

```
select count(distinct trope_id)
from movie_tropes t1
inner join movie_tropes t2 on t2.trope_id = t1.trope_id
where t1.movie_id = 1 and t2.movie_id = 2
```

But overall, you can compute the three base figures at once with two levels of aggregation. I would recommend:

```
select 
    sum(has_1) as cnt_1,            -- count of distinct tropes for movie 1
    sum(has_2) as cnt_2,            -- count of distinct tropes for movie 2
    sum(has_1 and has_2) as cnt_both  -- count of distinct tropes for both movies
from (
    select max(movie_id = 1) has_1, max(movie_id = 2) as has_2
    from movie_tropes t
    where movie_id in (1, 2)
    group by trope_id
) t
```

Comment: I understand how the sums work, once you have columns of 0s and 1s representing each trope's inclusion in a movie (or not). How does the inner select work, and how does it select 1s and 0s per trope?

Comment: Here, Inner query is grouped by `trope_id` and if `trope_id` present in `movie_id = 1` then `max(movie_id = 1)` will return 1 else it will return 0. the same way for `movie_id = 2`. and then based on binary `1` and `0`, outer query with `sum` works